# what should be the order of class names in sklearn tree export function (Beginner question on python sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying a simple example with sklearn decision tree. I am giving "number,is_power2,is_even" as features and the class is "is_even" (of course this is stupid)

Here is the code

```
from sklearn import tree

features =[[1,0,0] , [2,1,1] , [3,0,0] , [4,1,1] , [5,0,0] , [6,0,1] ,  [900,0,1] , [1001,0,0]] #val,pow2,even
labels =  ['o'     ,  'e'    , 'o'     ,  'e'    ,  'o'    ,  'e'    ,   'e'      ,  'o'] #is even

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features,labels)

print (clf.predict([[203,0,0]]))

import pydot

import pydotplus
from IPython.display import Image  
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                     feature_names=['number','pow2','even'],  
                     class_names=['o','e'],  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True)  
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  
# Image(graph.create_png())  
graph.write_pdf("1.pdf")
```

The decision tree correctly identifies even and odd numbers and the predictions are working properly.

The decision tree is basically like this (in pdf)

```
     is_even<=0.5
        /\
       /  \
   label1  label2
```

**The problem is this. The label1 is marked "o" and not "e".** However if I put class_names in export function as

`class_names=['e','o']`

then, the result is correct. I thought the output should be independent of class_names order.

Am I doing something wrong, or does the class_names order matter. If the latter is true, what is the right order (for an arbitrary problem)

Comment: Please refer this link for a more detailed answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724543/8696281

Comment: You can check `clf.classes_` to confirm class order.

Comment: @TakashiYoshino Yours should be the answer here, it would always give the right answer it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names should be given in ascending numerical order.

Saw this in the code's docs:

```
class_names : list of strings, bool or None, optional (default=None)
    Names of each of the target classes in ascending numerical order.
    Only relevant for classification and not supported for multi-output.
    If ``True``, shows a symbolic representation of the class name.
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the anwser, "ascending numerical order" what if it's a list of strings?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation. The names should be given in ascending order.

You can check the order used by the algorithm: the first box of the tree shows the counts for each class (of the target variable). The order es ascending of the class names

```
# class_names : list of strings, bool or None, optional (default=None)
# Names of each of the target classes in ascending numerical order.

class_names2pass = sorted(labels.unique())
print(class_names2pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is convert labels from string/char to numeric value. For instance 'o' = 0 and 'e' = 1

So your labels will look like this

```
labels =  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

class_names should match those numbers in ascending numeric order

```
0 - 'o'
1 - 'e'

class_names=['o', 'e']
```